# Как растянуть html страницу на всю высоту экрана

Tags: html, css

Всем доброго времени суток.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой - сайт не на всю высоту экрана,без понятия, что делать.
 Юзаю Bootstrap,возможно из-за него
Тоесть надо,чтобы body был 100% по высоте.
Заранее благодарю за ответы.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так он и не должен быть. У вас количество контента недостаточное, чтобы занимать всю высоту.
Посмотрите в гугле "как прижать футер к низу страницы".

Comment: @Oleksandr пля,точно,совсем затупил,благодарю за ответ :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте `body` минимальную высоту равную высоте экрана:

```
 body{min-height:100vh}
```

Comment: Это не повлияет, так как футер просто не прижимается к низу.

Comment: Каков вопрос - таков ответ. Вопрос был - "Как растянуть html страницу на всю высоту экрана"

Comment: Классно съехал. Респект 

Answer (score 0):

```
html{height: 100%;}
body {position:relative; min-height: 100%;}
.container{padding-bottom:5rem;}
footer{position:absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;}

<html>
<body>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```